# Word Embedding or Hash?

Tags: classification, lstm, preprocessing, word-embeddings, word2vec

In my dataset I have a 'text' column and a 'followers' column containing lists of follower IDs, i.e. '1093777852477116417, 936194589043683328,...'. Some of the 'followers' values contain thousands of IDs.

I am preprocessing the data for LSTM, and I will do word embedding on the text column.

My question is, should I add the follower IDs to the word embedding of the text column, or should I hash the follower IDs and add an extra LSTM input layer for the IDs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A classification task? Difficult to help without more context

Comment: I am trying to label articles as either fake or real, so yes its a classification task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends…

The general rule of thumb is that there should be at least 40 occurrences of an item to train an embedding model to find a robust representation. If most follower IDs repeat then an embedding model can learn which ones co-occur. If follower IDs are sparse then hashing (which randomly assigns numbers) is a better choice.

Which method is better is an empirical question. You can create both models, benchmark, and then choose the data processing pipeline that is best for your task.

Comment: Allright, I will try both methods and see what gives the best result :) Thank you